# Posting on user's facebook wall from C# Desktop application

Tags: c#, facebook

I want to publish a staus message + picture on the user's facebook page. DO NOT need to access user  information at all.

The application being used is a C# application running on windows.

The question is how to do that and do I need Facebook application ID ? even though I do not need to pull user info ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to get an app ID as you will be using facebook's API. The only way to integrate with facebook without app ID is to use social plugins but they don't support posting images nor c#